# How to show only a small part of the cited bibliography.

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, citing

I want to show only a part of my cited bibliography. In my MWE, I cited three references, but when calling my bibliography at the end of the document I just want to show the first reference of my bibliography. In other words, I need to cite three references and only display one of those three. I need this because it is an exposition and I need to talk about just a small part of the cited bibliography.

This is the code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{angulo2015dynamics,
  title={Dynamics and forecast in a simple model of sustainable development for rural populations},
  author={Angulo, David and Angulo, Fabiola and Olivar, Gerard},
  journal={Bulletin of mathematical biology},
  volume={77},
  number={2},
  pages={368--389},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@book{david,
Author = {Angulo García, David and Olivar Tost, Gerard},
Publisher = {Manizales, 2012.},
Title = {Esquemas de Desarrollo Sostenible : una Aplicación de Redes Complejas a la Región de Caldas = Sustainable development schemes: [recurso electrónico].},
URL = {http://ezproxy.unal.edu.co/login?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&db=cat02704a&AN=unc.000723149&lang=es&site=eds-live},
Year = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Justificación}

\footnotemark
\setcounter{footnote}{1} 
  \footnotetext{\cite{key}, \textsuperscript{2}\cite{angulo2015dynamics}, \cite{david}} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Referencias}
    \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}
\end{document
```

Comment: Would switching to biblatex be an option for you? This has the nice `refsection` mechanism, which would make this really easy

Comment: @samcarter How is the procedure for switching to biblatex?

Comment: I added a short example below. The main difference is that it needs to be compiled with `biber` instead of `bibtex`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex is a guide how to switch from bibtex to biblatex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With biblatex one could use a `\refsection` around your bibliography and add only the entries you'd like to cite with `\nocite`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{angulo2015dynamics,
  title={Dynamics and forecast in a simple model of sustainable development for rural populations},
  author={Angulo, David and Angulo, Fabiola and Olivar, Gerard},
  journal={Bulletin of mathematical biology},
  volume={77},
  number={2},
  pages={368--389},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@book{david,
Author = {Angulo García, David and Olivar Tost, Gerard},
Publisher = {Manizales, 2012.},
Title = {Esquemas de Desarrollo Sostenible : una Aplicación de Redes Complejas a la Región de Caldas = Sustainable development schemes: [recurso electrónico].},
URL = {http://ezproxy.unal.edu.co/login?url=http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&db=cat02704a&AN=unc.000723149&lang=es&site=eds-live},
Year = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Justificación}

\footnotemark
\setcounter{footnote}{1} 
  \footnotetext{\cite{key}, \textsuperscript{2}\cite{angulo2015dynamics}, \cite{david}} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Referencias}
    \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{key}
    \printbibliography
    \end{refsection}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the code is working? An error message is shown, It says that all the references are undefined

Comment: @JuanMuñoz Yes, I'm sure the code is working. Did you run biber?